# How can two developers work on same file using git

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I was using SVN last where two developers can work on same file . Suppose A developer edit the A.java on 31 line and Suppose B developer edit the A.java on 35 line.

In case of SVN first A developer commit the code then if  B second developer take update then that SVN code merge on local sytem of second B developer then can commit.

But this git does not allow. When two developers edited same file and one commited the source and other also edited same file it does not merge the code it gives below error.

Any solution to this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should commit your local changes, and then merge with the other user's changes - if you do a `pull` command, the merge will happen automatically, otherwise you have to `fetch` the remote branch and then `merge` to your local branch.

If you worked on different lines, the merge will succeed automatically. Otherwise, you might have to resolve conflicts manually.

Comment: so If he commited the source code then before I take pull Do I commit my code first then take pull of it ??

Comment: Yes, you always commit before merge. You may also commit several times before merging your (multiple) changes with his change(s).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Oh thank you :) I always ignored when I get this http://i.stack.imgur.com/SLEnO.png then I used to do it manually...so I will try your idea.